# Show that there are no rationals $r$ such that $r^3 = 6$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, rationality-testing

> Show that there are no rationals $r$ such that $r^3 = 6$

We were asked this for a real analysis assignment. I just assumed that it would be the same as if it were $r^2$, but now I'm second guessing myself.

Comment: Maybe you could phrase it more as a question? Also, what have you tried more specifically?

Comment: You are correct that the proof structure is nearly identical to the proof that there is no rational $r$ such that  $r^2 = 2$

Comment: Consider the function $\nu_2(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ that returns the largest $n$ with $2^n | x$.

Comment: I added the tags "prime-numbers" and "elementary-number-theory" to your post.  I suppose that the "real-analysis" tag is appropriate, at some level or other . .  .  Cheers!

Comment: Have you proven that each natural number has a unique prime factorization yet.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $r=\dfrac{a}{b}$ is a rational with $a,b$ coprime such that $r^3=6$

Then $a^3=6b^3$

The prime factorization of the LHS contains primes with powers which are multiple of $3$, and so does $b^3$ in the RHS.

But RHS contains factor $6=2\times 3$, therefore prime factors $2$ and $3$ in the RHS are NOT multiple of $3$ because their exponent is $3k+1;\;3h+1,\; k,h\in\mathbb{N}$

This is a contradiction so there is no rational $r$ such that $r^3=6$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $r \in \Bbb Q$ satisfies

$r^3 = 6; \tag 1$

then we can take

$r = \dfrac{p}{q}, \tag 2$

$p, q, \in \Bbb Z$, with

$\gcd(p, q) = 1; \tag 3$

thus

$\dfrac{p^3}{q^3} = \left ( \dfrac{p}{q} \right )^3 = r^3 = 6, \tag 4$

whence

$p^3 = 6q^3 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot q^3; \tag 5$

we have *via* (5) that

$2 \mid p^3; \tag 6$

it follows from (6) that $p$ is even; that is,

$p = 2s\tag 7$

for some $s \in \Bbb Z$; if this were not the case, so that $p$ were odd, we could write

$p = 2s + 1, \tag 8$

whence

$p^3 = (2s + 1)^3 = 8s^3 + 12s^2 + 6s + 1 = 2(4s^3 + 6s^2 + 3s) + 1, \tag 9$

which contradicts (6); thus (7) binds, and

$8s^3 = (2s)^3 = p^3 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot q^3, \tag{10}$

or

$4s^3 = 3 \cdot q^3, \tag{11}$

which in turn implies

$2 \mid 3 \cdot q^3. \tag{12}$

(12) forces $q$ to be even as well; that is, $q = 2t$ where $t \in \Bbb Z$; if this were not the case, if $q = 2t + 1$, then in a manner similar to the above we would have

$q^3 = 8t^3 + 12t^2 + 6t + 1, \tag{13}$

whence

$3 \cdot q^3 = 24t^3 + 36t^2 + 18t + 3 = 2(12t^3 + 18t^2 + 9t + 1) + 1, \tag{14}$

which contradicts (12); thus $q$ is even and we may take

$q = 2t. \tag{15}$

(7) and (15) together now contradict (3); thus we cannot find $p, q$ such that (1) and (2) hold; so,

$r \notin \Bbb Q. \tag{16}$

***Note:***  I have, in the above argument, explicitly tried to avoid invoking the fact that $2$ (or $3$ for that matter) is prime, which fact would immediately allow the conclusions (7) from (6) and (15) from (12) without the need to carry through the *reductio ad absurdum* demonstration embodied in (8)-(9) and (13)-(14); but I wanted to avoid using that for primes $k$

$[k \mid ab] \Longrightarrow [k \mid a \vee k \mid b], \tag{17}$

since I anticipate that many of the readers of this answer may not have encountered the notions of irreducible *vs.* prime and of principle ideal domain which links them in $\Bbb Z$.  So I tried to keep things as elementary as I could see my way to.  ***End of Note.***

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a very different answer from the usual ones for this kind of problem I find.

Let $\dfrac{p^3}{q^3}=6\lt2^3\Rightarrow \dfrac pq\lt 2$. Put then $\dfrac pq=2-h$ where $h$ is  positive. It follows
$$6=8-12h+6h^2-h^3\iff h^3-6h^2+12h-2=0$$ 
By Eisenstein's criterion for irreducibility with the prime $2$, the real root $h$ of this equation is not rational ($h\approx 0.1829$). Consequently $2-h$ is not rational. Contradiction, $\dfrac pq$ can not be a rational.

Answer (score 1):

**Another way** to attack such problems is using polynomials with integer coefficients and [Rational root theorem (RTT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). In this case the polynomial is 
$$P(x)=x^3-6$$
Now, let's assume $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. From RTT, $r$ as a solution of $P(x)$, can only be an integer (or irrational, but we skip this part since we assumed $r \in \mathbb{Q}$), since the leading coefficient of $P(x)$ is $1$, so $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, we have an integer $r$ s.t. 
$$r^3=6=2\cdot 3 \tag{1}$$
or $3 \mid r\cdot r\cdot r$ which (from [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) and since $3$ is prime) means $3 \mid r$. In another words, $\exists q\in \mathbb{Z}, q\ne0: r=3\cdot q$. Applying this to (1) we have
$$3\cdot q \cdot 3\cdot q \cdot 3\cdot q=6 \Rightarrow 3^2\cdot q^3=2$$
which means $3 \mid 2$ - contradiction. Thus $r \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Having $r=p/q$ written in lowest terms, then $p^3/q^3$ is in lowest terms too. But $p^3/q^3=r^3=6/1$ and since the fractions can be written in lowest terms in exactly one way (with positive denominator), then $p^3=6$. Clearly no integer satisfies this equality.

Note: Showing the uniqueness of lowest terms invokes use of unique prime factorization, but it is commonly known that this holds for rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The question is do you know the prime factorization theorem or not.

It's not significantly different than showing there is no rational $r$ so that $r^2 = 2$ but....

if $r = \frac mn; m,n \in \mathbb Z$ and $\frac mn$ is in "lowest terms" so that $r^3 = 6$ then $6n^3 = m^3$ which if we accept the PFT then the prime factors of $m^3$ are all to multiples of $3$ powers whereas the powers of $2$ and $3$ of $6n^3$ will be one more than multiples of $3$.

... which is how we prove that if $r^n = k \in \mathbb Z$ then $r$ is an integer are $k$ is a perfect $n$ power.

But if we can't use PFT, the replicating the old square root of $2$ prove.  $m^3$ is even.  If $m$ is odd then $m^3$ is odd. So $m$ is even.  So $8|6n^3$ so $4|3n^3$ so $3n^2 $ is even.  If $n$ is odd, so is $3n^3$ so $n$ is even.  But that contradicts that $\frac mn$ was in "lowest terms".

And .... the factor of $3$ didn't really have much to do with it.

Of course, we could have used that $6$ is a multiple of $3$ rather than it was even:  $6n^3 = m^3$ so $3|m^3$ if $m = 3k + i$ then $m^3 = 27k^3 + 27k^2 + 9k^3 + i^3$ and if $i = 1, 2$ then $3\not \mid i^3$ so $3|m$ so $27|6n^3$ and $3|2n^3$ and if $n = 3j +i$ then $2n^3 = 54j^3 + 54j^2 + 18k^3 + 2i$ and if $i= 1,2$ then $3 \not \mid 2i^3$ so $3|n$ and ... not in lowest terms.

It... gets pretty repetitive.  Best learn the PFT once and for all.